# What is the recommendation about using multiprocessing (or multithreading) inside a flask endpoint?

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing

I know that an app server can be configured to:

1. Launch new process per request
2. Launch new thread per request

This question is regarding using python multi-processing (or multi-threading) code inside a flask endpoint. For example say I want to use python multiprocessing for CPU intensive work (or multithreading for IO intensive work).

I have a flask endpoint that takes 40 seconds to run the code (CPU intensive work). I have used python multiprocessing (pool) inside the endpoint code [so that certain CPU intensive things can be done in parallel via multiple processes] and now the endpoints takes 4 seconds to run.

Is it OK to use python multiprocessing (or multithreading) code inside an endpoint when either of the above 2 app server configurations (that is  -when the app server is configured to serve each request in a new thread or each new request in a new process). The thread per request is default setting of the flask development server. Where as for gunicorn I can choose either. Is there anything I need to consider when using multiprocessing (or multithreading) inside a flask endpoint so that I am not messing up with the flask process/thread.

I know that a better solution is to use a task queue. But this question is specifically regarding using multithreading/multiprocessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, don't. It's tempting to try to negotiate some way to do a lot of work directly within a request handler, but that path leads to pain.

Consider instead one of the frameworks that allows a request handler (e.g., a Flask route) to queue up a task to be run asynchronously. The handler queues work, and gets back a task id, saving it in some way that allows the UI to poll for task completion. Meanwhile, an entirely separate process outside of flask picks up work, performs it, and returns a response through the framework (or separately via a shared data store).

[Celery](https://pypi.org/project/celery/) and [Rq](https://pypi.org/project/rq/) are two of such frameworks. (The [Flask Mega Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs) has a chapter on Rq that's worth a read.) They do require some additional setup. At a minimum, you'll need a shared [Redis](https://redis.io/) instance.

This approach has several benefits: First, it allows your web app to remain responsive. If your 40 second task evolves into an 80, 160, or several thousand second task, you won't tie up a Flask thread. Second, it protects Flask against memory growth and fragmentation; the task is performed in an entirely separate process, which will release memory when it exits.

What you do in those tasks is isolated from Flask. Want to use multiple processes or thread pools with a task? Fine. There's very little* risk of interfering with Flask. (* You could exhaust memory if you're running tasks workers on the same server as Flask).

Comment: I know that a better solution is to use a task queue. But this question is specifically regarding using multithreading/multiprocessing.

Comment: The risk you run trying to do this in the request thread/webserver process is that at some point (unless this is a single-user app), you're going to get multiple requests to that endpoint competing for resources (cores, memory), and something will fail. Likely, a request will time out. If you're unlucky, the Flask instance seizes up.

Comment: Dave - you are correct when it comes to a user facing app. But if flask api has a POST endpoint that is meant to be used by another api, where-in it accepts a file, processes it and returns the response, then are you saying I must not use multiprocessing?

Comment: @variable I've not seen that approach (or using multiprocessing to parallelize work across cores from within a request) work in Flask without strange side-effects. I haven't tracked down why. The reliable pattern I've fallen back on is to queue to work for an out of Flask process worker (using Celery or Rq), and handing back a 'ticket' to the caller that they can use to poll for status. It's more work, but is highly reliable.

Answer (score 8):

Using multiprocessing / thread-pools in Flask to run background or long running tasks is an anti-pattern. You should not do it. Flask is meant to serve APIs and do CRUD.

To solve your problem, consider using API <> Worker pattern.

```
Flask app --- REDIS (or other MQ) --- Celery App
    |                                         |
    +---> SQL/Database <----------------------+
```

Flask will receive API requests and perform basic CRUD (basically any operation related to the database) and nothing more.

For any long-running operation, commit the operation into the DB and the handle is enqueued into the redis/or-any-message-queue.

The celery is the job management framework that picks up these jobs from the queue and executes them (these jobs could run for a long period of time) and keep updating the DB on the progress.

Celery: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html

Comment: I know that a better solution is to use a task queue. But this question is specifically regarding using multithreading/multiprocessing.

Comment: Also, regarding your answer, I want to ask - Celery does the job management. Job status/results are stored in the database. So what exactly is the purpose of MQ?

Comment: The job of the MQ (aka broker in celery parlance) is to act as a queue to place jobs and also possibly use It as results (place results after the job has been processed). Multiple workers can be launched and they will listen to the broker. One of the workers will pick up the task and run it. There are ways to hand a task to a different worker if the one that took the task fails or times out.