# Why is document.py:__setattr__() getting called more times after switching regular object with MongoEngine document

Tags: python, mongoengine

I'm new to Python and have been tasked with optimizing some code and am trying to understand why my change has slowed things down. The code I'm working with is in a backend flask app.

The changes I made involved removing the use of temporary object that was being used to store data before copying all fields to a MongoEngine document object. All fields would get assigned to this temporary object, and then there was a conversion function that cast all fields to their proper data types for storage. Instead of using this temporary object, I just instantiated the MongoEngine document and replaced all lines that were assigning to the temporary object to instead assign to the document. I didn't add any lines, just replaced existing ones.

When I checked the changes using the Werkzeug Application Profiler for flask. It's showing 336,897 calls to `__setattr__()` before the changes and 502,953 calls after the changes.

I'm just wondering if there's any explanation for this other than me inadvertently increasing the calls somehow (I don't think this is the case because I've reviewed the changes in using git diff a few times and I didn't notice anything).

I appreciate any help I can get. Sorry for not providing any code examples (don't want to expose the companies code). However, if needed I can try my best to write some example code to show what I did.

Before:
[`__setattr()__` calls before changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFFxc.png)

After:
[`__setattr()__` calls after changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F833.png)

Comment: The description you give of the changes you made isn't nearly explicit enough for us to give you a sensible answer. `__setattr()__` gets called every time there is an assignment to an attribute of the object. It is probable that your changes had the side-effect of increasing the number of assignments, and my guess is that it had something to do with nested attributes, but without a before-and-after example of the code it's impossible to be sure. I can't imagine why your management thinks that this sort of optimization task is a job for a beginner.

Comment: Ok, thanks for taking the time to respond.

What are other options for optimizing computationally intensive requests in flask? I've considered multi-processing but after looking around I've seen some people say it's an anti-pattern (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68126489/what-is-the-recommendation-about-using-multiprocessing-or-multithreading-insid).

I'm thinking it might be a good idea to just do the processing in the background and send a email to the user once it's finished, instead of doing it in real-time.

Comment: Processing in background sounds both realistic and achievable, if your users will accept it.